# How to apply function to GroupBy agg

Tags: python

I have the following groupby which does not work well since I want to sum absolute values.

```
DF.groupby(["Name"], as_index=False).agg({"A":"sum",'B': 'first'}).round(2)
```

How can I add a rule which convert value to absolute before doing the sum ?

| Name | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Test | 3 | Blabla |
| Test | -3 |  |

The output I currently have is

| Name | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Test | 0 | Blabla |

The Excepted output is

| Name | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Test | 6 | Blabla |

How would I `apply` a function that take the absolute values and then sum these ?

```
.apply(lambda Nb: Nb.abs().sum())
```

Note that I know how to do It without agg :

```
DF.groupby(["Name"], as_index=False)['A'].apply(lambda Nb: Nb.abs().sum()).round(2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might provide functions as values of dict you are passing to [`pandas.DataFrame.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html), consider following example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['A','A','B','B','C','C'],'Value':[-1,2,-3,4,-5,6]})
grouped = df.groupby('Name').agg({'Value':lambda x:sum(abs(x))})
print(grouped)
```

output

```
      Value
Name
A         3
B         7
C        11
```

Comment: Thanks v Much, I didn't knew that it was that powerful ! Will accept in 5mn